# C# ASP.NET Web Application GridView 'Update' disabled after insertion of values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, gridview

I am writing a web application that binds database data to a gridview. The gridview editing is enabled.

What I want to do is when the 'Edit' link on the gridview is pressed and the row cells are enabled for editing I use a dropdownlist and button to insert the selected dropdownlist item into the field. This works, but as soon as it is added to the cell, the cell is not enabled (still with the new value inside). After this happens the 'Update' link on the gridview does not respond and update the database.

If I redo the process, press 'Update', insert a new value to the enabled cell by clicking on it and changing the text by keyboard, then the 'Update' command works.

When I manually trigger the 'Update' command in code with the first procedure adding it by dropdownlist, this is the error I get:

**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'For Action', table 'Mailregister.dbo.foraction';column does not allow nulls. Update Fails.**

I have checked the database and confirmed that it does not allow nulls, I can fix this, but I checked the values sent to the gridview is not NULL. So why would it think that it gets NULLS?

**UPDATE - code**

Code running when button is pressed to insert items into gridview cells:

```
 string dateForAction = ddlYearStartForAction.SelectedItem.Text + "/" + ddlMonthStartForAction.SelectedItem.Value + "/" + ddlDayStartForAction.SelectedItem.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gvwAction.Rows[gvwAction.EditIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString()))
            {
                gvwAction.Rows[gvwAction.EditIndex].Cells[1].Text = "Insert Name";
            }

            gvwAction.Rows[gvwAction.EditIndex].Cells[1].Text = ddlForAction.SelectedItem.Text;
            gvwAction.Rows[gvwAction.EditIndex].Cells[2].Text = dateForAction;

gvwAction.UpdateRow(gvwAction.EditIndex, true);
```

The gridview source code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwAction" runat="server" AllowCustomPaging="True" OnRowUpdating="gvwForaction_Updating" OnRowUpdated="RowUpdated" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceForAction" ForeColor="Black" Height="76px" PageSize="5" Width="288px" OnRowDeleting ="gvwAction_SelectedDeleteChange" OnRowEditing ="gvwAction_SelectedEditChanged" DataKeyNames="ForActionID" ShowFooter="True">
                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ForAction" HeaderText="ForAction" SortExpression="ForAction" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ActionCopyBack" HeaderText="ActionCopyBack" SortExpression="ActionCopyBack" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="RegID" HeaderText="RegID" SortExpression="RegID" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ForActionID" HeaderText="ForActionID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ForActionID" />
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Please use profiler tool and check the query, so you can be 100% sure that the value is not null.

Comment: show your code please